# Get only all Selected Members

Tags: c#, ssas, mdx

I am working with SSAS 2012.

I build my cube, so far everything is ok. I only have one problem.

I want to get all Selected Members in my list in excel.

Here is the example:

[image]

I tried to MDX expressions and none returned my what I want.

```
Generate((Existing [SKU].[Month].[Month]),  [SKU].[Month].Currentmember.name, ", ")
Generate(Nonempty( [SKU].[Month].[Month]),  [SKU].[Month].Currentmember.name, ", ")
```

I want the result to be like this: February, January, May!

For the 3 lines in the excel

```
Line1=February,January,may
Line2=February,January,may
Line3=February,January,may
```

My cube contains 9 month.

My current selection as per the image is only 3 month.

I want the mdx to return to me the selected month in every line of the excel sheet.

thanks,

Comment: Is the month shown as "Month Key" in your screen shot the same month hierarchy as `[SKU].[Month].[Month]`? Or do you have more than one month hierarchy, and reference different ones at different places?

Comment: i have [SKU].[Month].&[231] and [SKU].[Hierarchy].[Month].&[231]

Comment: So columns "Year Key" and "Month Key" are from "[SKU].[Hierarchy]"? Could you capture the MDX SELECT statement sent to your server from Excel, as described at http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/101/Posts/15762/mdx-9-capture-mdx-queries-with-sql-server-profiler.aspx, and post it?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8onHvwlltS4MmN1dFlyS0o4Ylk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: this is the MDX from SQL Profiler
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8onHvwlltS4MmN1dFlyS0o4Ylk/edit?usp=sharing


this is the MDX from the EXcel:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8onHvwlltS4TGxRSXBiaEhzcm8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: here is the calculated measure from EXcel
Generate(([SKU].[Month].[month].members),  [SKU].[Month].Currentmember.name, ", ")

Comment: The MDX seems to show that you have put all attributes of the SKU dimension into one hierarchy named `Hierarchy`. I am not sure a cube design like this works. Why did you not put the time related attributes into a `Time` hierarchy (that would then be a real hierarchy like Year - quarter - month), and use other hierearchies for otehr attributes, as appropriate?

Comment: is what you said is related to what i need ?
let us say this is the design for the time being, so how can get the data i want for now.

thanks for helping me

Comment: I am not sure if that matters or not, but it surely influences the `[SKU].[Hierarchy].Currentmember`. As an approach to solve your problem: What happens if you use `Generate((Existing [SKU].[Hierarchy].[Month]),  [SKU].[Hierarchy].Currentmember.name, ", ")`? Or when you put the filter on the month attribute instead of teh month level of the hierarchy?

Comment: Generate((Existing  [SKU].[Hierarchy].[Month]),  [SKU].[Hierarchy].Currentmember.name, ", ")
the result is:
April
January
May

this is not what i want.

this is what i want:
Line1=February,January,may
Line2=February,January,may
Line3=February,January,may

Comment: this part of your question i cant understand 
"Or when you put the filter on the month attribute instead of teh month level of the hierarchy?"

Comment: Do you see the Month attribute within the SKU dimension, in parallel to your "Hierarchy"? If not, you made it invisible in your dimension design. If it would be visible, you could use it in the filter. And the result may be different from what you have. Anyway, I do not think it is worth trying to get a wrong design to work. I would rather suggest to get the design correct. Your approach is a bit like a SQL table with just one column of type char which is used for dates, integers, texts, etc. You need a lot of application logic to get around the design that the tool is not designed for.

Comment: help me and tell me how to do it.

Comment: Well, the first step would be to properly design the cube (dimensions, fact tables, measures, ...). Not knowing your source data, this is really difficult to do.